# Keep unversioned files when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Everytime I run *cap deploy* in the remote server I lost some unversioned files because capistrano creates a new directory and checkouts the head revision in it. But there are some files that are not versioned like users avatars (paperclip) and uploaded images which don't get copied to the new current release.

How can I workaround this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I think the best way to deal with those kind of things is to store them in the shared folder and create a task in capistrano to create symlinks to the shared assets.

Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
set :shared_assets, %w{public/images/products public/images/barcodes}

namespace :assets  do
  namespace :symlinks do
    desc "Setup application symlinks for shared assets"
    task :setup, :roles => [:app, :web] do
      shared_assets.each { |link| run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/#{link}" }
    end

    desc "Link assets for current deploy to the shared location"
    task :update, :roles => [:app, :web] do
      shared_assets.each { |link| run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/#{link} #{release_path}/#{link}" }
    end
  end
end

before "deploy:setup" do
  assets.symlinks.setup
end

before "deploy:symlink" do
  assets.symlinks.update
end
```

Comment: I understand but... that "shared" dir is a capistrano thing, Rails does not know about it as far as I know. So, how do I suppose to tell rails to save files in that directory, which is outside the application and it doesn't event exists in my local copy?

Comment: You don't change anything in Rails. That's the point of this tactic. Rails still saves the images to "RAILS_ROOT/public/images/avatars" or whatever, but that folder is actually a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to a folder in capistrano's "shared" folder.

Answer (score 8):

Adding your paths to shared_children also works and is actually just a one-liner in your deploy.rb:

```
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
```

found it here: [astonj](http://astonj.com/tech/how-to-get-capistrano-to-ignore-upload-directories-carrierwave/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is very tiny and useful gem: https://github.com/teohm/capistrano-shared_file. Check the gem's docs — everything is simple.

Install gem, in `deploy.rb` require it and just provide an array of files you wish to share between releases in `shared_files` option:

```
set :shared_files, %w(config/database.yml)
```

Store your files at `<project_dir>/shared/files/YOUR_FILE_GOES_HERE`. And they will be symlinked to root of your application at each deploy. Thats all.